# Whom do I have to contact for a ticket refund in case of denied boarding (in the EU)?

Tags: eu, cancellations, refunds

I have bought tickets for a flight with Etihad Airways through Flighttix.

Due to the current unexpected political unrest in Pakistan, the airports over there have been closed and therefore I was denied boarding in Frankfurt. Obviously I now want a refund for my ticket.

I am however not sure, who to contact about this - Flighttix or Etihad? On the web, I found contradicting information. Etihad states on their website to contact the third party seller, but some websites suggest to always contact the airline rather than the ticket seller.

In either case, it is hard to get a correct address to send the refund request to, but I guess a mail is not sufficient, is it?

Comment: If Flighttix said "Contact Etihad" and Etihad said "Contact Flighttix", you'd have a problem. But, as it is, Etihad, who should know what they're talking about, say "Contact Flighttix" and random other people who have no connection to the case say "Contact Etihad." So you contact Flighttix.

Comment: I made an edit because "denied boarding" is usually used when the flight happens as expected but they won't let you get on it. A cancelled flight is different.

Comment: For security reasons, refunds often have to go to the payment method used for the initial payment. As you have most probably made the payment to Flighttix, not Etihad, then it's them who will refund you, and them you should contact.

Comment: Actually, the plane Frankfurt to Abu Dhabi left, and apperantly so did the second flight which would have brought me to my destination. However, they didn't let me board in Frankfurt, so yes, I was denied boarding.

Comment: That's probably a good thing. Presumably you live in or near Frankfurt if you have decided not to travel. Had they boarded you, you would be stuck in Abu Dhabi.

Comment: So the flight _did_ run? Then what does this have to do with closed airports? Why were you denied boarding?

Comment: I got a paper at the airport saying, that the second flight was cancelled. However, when I was home I checked the flights, and according to the Etihad webpage, the second flight did land in pakistan as planned (or rather with a short delay).
We were told that currently the airports are closed in Pakistan, so they were not allowed to let us on board. I pointed out that they were planned to reopen before our arrival, but we were told that currently that didn't matter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Etihad could possibly help you rebook your ticket on a new flight, but if you want a refund, you need to first contact the ticket seller.

Comment: Yes, they offered to rebook the flight, however I decided against that. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Just as an update, I got a response from flight tix saying that they now contact Etihad in order to get the refund. They mentioned however, that if I was not okay with that, I may contact Etihad directly.

Answer (score 8):

In most countries, you would have to request a refund from Flighttix, the ticket seller.
In some countries, customer is protected by joint and several liability. In this case, if Flighttix is uncooperative, you could legally request a refund from Etihad.
You **cannot**, however, request a refund from both parties at the same time.